# Python CSV dictReader, not getting expected output

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, visual-studio-code, file-handling

Below is the code, opening the file and passing it to CSV handler in python

```
def csv_reader_dict():
  #Reading Data From CSV file into Dictionary using csv
  print("---------Reading Data From CSV file into Dictionary using csv------------")
  with open('input.txt','r') as file_data:
    csv_format = csv.DictReader(file_data)
    line_count2 = 0
    for row in csv_format:
        if line_count2 == 0:
            print("Header are {}".format(",".join(row) ))
            line_count2 += 1
        else:
            print("{} reside at {} and joined on {}".format(row["name"],row["address"],row["date joined"]))
            line_count2 += 1
    print("Processed {} line count".format(line_count2))
  print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
  print("\n")

csv_reader_dict()
```

#### Expected Output:

[image: Expected Output]

#### Actual Output:

[image: Actual Output]

Comment: What's the data, what's the expected output, what are you getting?

Comment: Added image of output

Comment: What's is the content of the data? Columns are separatted by commas? Addresses can be conflicting with CSV separators.

Comment: name,address,date joined
john smith,"1132 Anywhere Lane Hoboken NJ, 07030",Jan 4
erica meyers,"1234 Smith Lane Hoboken NJ, 07030",March 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DictReader assumes the first row to be headers so it skips it. In your code you are using your first iteration to print headers and not the required information.

Adding `fieldnames` to `DictReader` should work because it will not skip the first row and your code will work as intended.

```
def csv_reader_dict():
#Reading Data From CSV file into Dictionary using csv
print("---------Reading Data From CSV file into Dictionary using csv------------")
with open('input.txt','r') as file_data:
    csv_format = csv.DictReader(file_data, fieldnames=['name', 'address', 'date joined'])
    line_count2 = 0
    for row in csv_format:
        if line_count2 == 0:
            print("Header are {}".format(",".join(row) ))
            line_count2 += 1
        else:
            print("{} reside at {} and joined on {}".format(row["name"],row["address"],row["date joined"]))
            line_count2 += 1
    print("Processed {} line count".format(line_count2))
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

When `line_count2 == 0` it's iterating through the first row (john smith), and you are forcing when `line_count2 == 0` to print the header.

You think that the line `print("Header are {}".format(",".join(row) ))` it's printing the header, but it's printing the keys of the first row, that are the same headers.

You can simplify the function:

```py
def csv_reader_dict():
    #Reading Data From CSV file into Dictionary using csv
    print("---------Reading Data From CSV file into Dictionary using csv------------")
    with open('input.txt','r') as file_data:
        csv_format = csv.DictReader(file_data)
        line_count2 = 0
        print("Header are {}".format(",".join(csv_format.fieldnames)))
        for row in csv_format:
            print("{} reside at {} and joined on {}".format(row["name"],row["address"],row["date joined"]))
            line_count2 += 1
    print("Processed {} line count".format(line_count2))
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("\n")

csv_reader_dict()
```